# Regular expressions giving unexpected results whith [:space:]

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm learning how to use regular expressions in R, but struggling a bit.
I understood from [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) and [other sources](http://informatique-mia.inra.fr/r4ciam/node/148) that `.` represent any character and that `*` means that the previously staten pattern may occur any number of time.

So if I try something like :

```
gsub(".* ","test_","abcd efgh")
```

The part of the string prior to the space is replaced and I get "test_efgh", as expected.

I then tried to use `[:space:]` instead of " ". From R documentation :

> [:space:]
>
> Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters

But I got quite different outputs, as shown below :

```
gsub(".*[:space:]","test_","abcd efgh")
#"test_fgh" : "e" is missing
gsub(".*[:space:]","test_","bcd df")
#"test_d df" : the first "d" was not replaced
gsub(".*[:space:]","test_","bcd bcde")
#"test_" : everything was cleared after the space
gsub(".*[:space:]","test_","bb df")
#"bb_df" : nothing was replaced
```

All these examples work fine if I use " " instead of `[:space:]`, so I guess I'm missing something about the latter. I don't understand why it doesn't apply in these cases, and I don't get why the outputs are so different (in cases 1 and 3, letters I wanted to keep were cleared whereas in cases 2 and 4, letters I wanted cleared were not).

How should I use `[:space:]`, and why do I get different outputs from seemingly identical uses ?

Comment: The `[:space:]` bracket expression matches a single char: `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c` or `e`. Use the POSIX character class inside a bracket expression: `[[:space:]]`.